# How can i do series command in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have to issue a series of commands, all in the form as shown below:

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 2.mp4
>   ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 2_2.mp4
>   ffmpeg -i 3.mp4 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 3_2.mp4
>   ffmpeg -i 4.mp4 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 4_2.mp4

Please show me how can I issue all commands automatically or do it with one command.

Answer (score 2):

## use a loop

If you're a Linux or OS X user then you can use a Bash *for loop*:

```
mkdir outputdir
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -vf scale=640:-2 -c:a copy "outputdir/${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Maybe a Windows user can add a similar example that works for that OS.

## or simply cram it all in one command

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 \
-map 0 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 1_2.mp4 \
-map 1 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 2_2.mp4 \
-map 2 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 3_2.mp4 \
-map 3 -s 640x480 -c:a copy 4_2.mp4
```

You have to use [`-map`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) otherwise the default [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will choose the same input for each output.